# Vlookup with multiplication using collection/dictionary or classes

Tags: excel, vba, class, dictionary, excel-formula

My problem is the following, I have a trial balance (list of accounts ran for multiple months with their ending balance in various currencies) and a second sheet showing fxrate conversion rates to USD for those months. First sheet could have hundreds of thousands of lines, while the second around 150-200 rows. A quick extract of those two sheets would look as follows:

1st sheet:

```
A - Month; B - Currency; C - ending balance; Col D (USD); Col E (USD per Dec-18 rate)  
Dec-18         EUR               12000  
Dec-18         GBP               55000  
Dec-18         SEK               1500000  
Mar-19         EUR               60000  
Mar-19         GBP               1700  
Mar-19         SEK               500
```

2nd sheet:

```
A - Month; B - Currency;    C - fxrate
Dec-18         EUR               0.9
Dec-18         GBP               0.7
Dec-18         SEK               9.3
Mar-19         EUR               0.85
Mar-19         GBP               0.75
Mar-19         SEK               9.1
```

My goal is to:

- fill in Col D from 1st sheet by multiplying Col C with fxrate value from Col C from 2nd sheet AND do that for the matching month. So in D1 I'd like to find what fxrate for EUR for Dec-18 is (0.9) and multiply 12000 by that value. However for D4 I'd like to know fxrate for EUR for Mar-19 (0.85) and multiply 60000 by that value
- fill in COl E from 1st sheet by choosing upfront from which month I would like to use the fxrate from (no matter what month is stated in Col A in 1st sheet). So for example I could assing to some variable "Dec-18" and then use only fxrates from Dec-18 for the whole list of items on 1st sheet. So this time in E2 I would multiply 12000 by 0.9 (same as above), however for E4 I would multiply 6000 but again by 0.9 (not 0.85).

I've looked at posts on regular vlookup, on dictionaries and classes but I could no answer to that question. Can anyone help and at least guide me towards a partial solution which I could try to enhance on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a trick and use `SUMIFS`. Since we can assume that every `Month`-`Currency` combination in Sheet2 is unique that will return the actual `fxrate` because the sum of only one unique entry is the value itself:

This formula will return `fxrate`

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet2!C:C,Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!B:B,Sheet1!B:B)
```

And you just need to multiply that with column C

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet2!C:C,Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!B:B,Sheet1!B:B)*C:C
```

to get your result (use this formula for column D).

For column E it is almost the same formula you just need to write your fixed month value somewhere and use this cell in the `SUMIFS` as criteria instead of column A.

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet2!C:C,Sheet2!A:A,$I$2,Sheet2!B:B,Sheet1!B:B)*C:C
```

I used cell `$I$2` (see the red in the example below):

Sheet1
[image]

Sheet2
[image]

Comment: Hi PEH, in theory I was looking for automatic solution, because I wanted to add several steps that would analyze that data afterwards, but this formula is still a much shorter, better and quicker version then the one we had previously with SUMPRODUCT. Thank you for helping out

Comment: Thanks PEH, I just did.